# Animation in angular ui bootstrap alerts

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to add animations to the alerts provided by angular ui bootstrap?
I am particularly interested in fading in an alert that lingers for a while before it automatically fades out again.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I created the following classes to do just that:

```
.alert.ng-hide-add,
.alert.ng-hide-remove {

    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;

    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
}


.alert.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The documentation for animating the ng-hide directive can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) see the Animations section.

Comment: Cool. Do you have a plunker for that?